# Ayuda tengo problema con un div

Tags: php, html, yii2

Buen dia, me veo obligado a solicitar su ayuda, les consulto tengo un formulario que tengo lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'cd_categoria',['labelOptions'=>['style'=>'color:black']])->dropdownList($model->getListaCategoria(), ['prompt' => '---Seleccione Categoria---',

['maxlength'=>50,'style'=>'width:500px; color:black; ',
'onChange'=>'
$.post("list?id='.'"+$(this).val(), function(data) {
if(data=="1"){
$( "#result" ).show();
}else{
$( "#result" ).hide();
}


});']]) ?>
<div id="result" style="display:none;">
<?= $form->field($model, 'nu_personas',['labelOptions'=>['style'=>'color:black']])->textInput([['maxlength'=>50,'style'=>'width:500px; color:black; ']]) ?>
</div>

public actionList($id){
if($id==19){
echo "1";
}else{
echo "0";
}

}
```

Lo que necesito hacer es que cuando seleccione el div, una opcion especifica me muestre el div de abajo el del ``nu_personas` y si no que siga sin mostrarmelo alguien me puede decir que puede estar pasando

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo el Form de arriba siempre se esta escribiendo, tienes que poner un condicional para mostrar uno u Otro Form.

```
<?=
**if (mostrar) {**
$form->field($model, 'cd_categoria',
['labelOptions'=>  
['style'=>'color:black']])->dropdownList($model->getListaCategoria(),  
['prompt' => '---Seleccione Categoria---',
}
```

Comment: El div que quiero mostrar es que el tengo abajo el que `nu_personas`

Answer (score 0):

a mi esto me funciona bien .

**Controller** TestController.php

```
  public function actionList($id)
    {
        if ($id == 1) {
            echo "1";
        } else {
            echo "0";
        }

    }
```

**View** test/index.php

```
  <?= Html::dropDownList(
    'testName',
    '2',
    [
        'none' => "Nothing",
        '1' => '1',
        '2' => '2',
        '3' => '3',
        '4' => '4',
    ],
    [
        'maxlength' => 50,
        'style' => 'width:500px; color:black; ',
        'onChange' => '
        $.post("list?id=' . '"+$(this).val(),
             function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                if(data=="1"){
                    $( "#result" ).show();
                }else{
                    $( "#result" ).hide();
                }           
            }
        );'
    ]) ?>


<div id="result" style="display:none;">
    aaa
</div>
```

> El titulo de tu función debería ser *public **function** actionList($id)*  y no    *public actionList($id)*